# In PHP can a StdClass's value be the value of another key?

Tags: php

Not sure how to word this question.

Is it possible to create a new StdClass and have one value be the value of another key(property)?

**Without acreating a class**

```
$myObject = (object) [
  'base_url' => 'http://www.google.com/',
  'route'    => $this->base_url . '/some/deeper/path'
];
```

I know this code is incorrect, but focusing on replacing `$this` just for getting the concept across.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Are you attempting to have the replacement happen in the `(object)` conversion? In other words, have the `route` property automatically assume its value based on another property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your array creation is done as a single step, and the source of base_url doesn't exist yet, only as seperate actions, you need to set to get :)

```
$myObject = new stdClass();
$myObject->base_url = 'http://www.google.com';
$myObject->route = $myObject->base_url . '/some/deeper/path';
```

---

Edit: you could use a varaible assignment in the middle of your one liner...

```
$myObject = (object) [
  'base_url' => $base_url = 'http://www.google.com/',
  'route'    => $base_url . '/some/deeper/path'
];
//unset( $base_url );
```

Because the action of `$base_url = 'http://www.google.com/'` happens first before the object creation, thus making a two step process.

Comment: nailed it. thanks. Do I need to unset that variable?

Comment: Not really, it depends on the scope/context if where this code will run. If its in a self contained function then its going to get cleared at end of running, otherwise if its in the global scope, just make sure its not going to conflict with anything. I just put it there as a reminder that somtimes you need to clear your temp variables :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a dynamic PHP property using the magic `__get` method. For example:

```
<?php
class MyClass {
    public $base_url = 'http://www.google.com/';

    public function __get($name) {
        if ($name == 'route') {
            return rtrim($this->base_url,'/') . '/some/deeper/path';
        }

        throw new \Exception("Property '$name' is not set");
    }
}
```

Do this on `stdClass` you could subclass it. However `stdClass` is just like an initial base class anyway.

Comment: I'm not wanting to create an class as this is just an inline object used for mapping JSON for simplicity.